Citrix ICAclient HDX has detected corrupted server data session can not continue
I have been trying to figure this out for days now.  I have this problem every time I re-image my computer. Somehow it just starts working, but it takes me days of trying things and then by accident it will just start working.
I am so tired of this and hope someone can help with a set of steps that will fix this every time.  Currently I put Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop and am trying to get the ICAclient to work.It will work if I use Firefox, but the display is cut off when I use the remote desktop app from my company.
When I use chrome, it just downloads the .ica file and when I open the file, the Citrix Workspace starts to run and then I get an error dialog that says:
"HDX has detected corrupted server data session can not continue"
and this is what I get in the logfile: /var/log/citrix/ICAClient.log
2024-07-02 13:37:55.302 [WD:ERROR] <P2687:T2687> citrix-wfica: [wfica]: %!FUNC!: FATAL ERROR 210 
2024-07-02 13:37:55.302 [WD:ERROR] <P2687:T2687> citrix-wfica: [wfica]: UNRECOVERABLE EXPANSION ERROR - ASSUME CORRUPT HOST 
2024-07-02 13:37:55.302 [LIBS:ERROR] <P2687:T2687> citrix-wfica: [wfica]: error on dialog title:Network data corrupted body:HDX has detected corrupted server data, session can not continue. 

I have tried adding certs, copying certs, disabling ipv6, changing dns servers, just about everything I could find on the tubes.
Does anyone have any definitive way of fixing this?
Thanks in advance,
Paul

After days of messing with this, I finally decided to uninstall the latest client and install an older one.  I installed:  icaclient_23.11.0.82_amd64.deb and it just worked straight away.
I have no idea why citrix can't get their act together.  Anyway, if you have the HDX error, try installing an older version.

Thank you very much Paul, I saw the same on Fedora. I tried some recent versions without success but I confirm it works with icaclient_23.11.0.82, the RPM version in my case.
